# iphone ios8 - playing audio in background iOS8

Tags: iphone, audio, ios8

All:

I have had many apps that play audio in the background when the user hits the home button or puts the phone to sleep. These apps have worked for years from iOS4 through iOS7.

Now in iOS8 the background audio playing sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.  I have not changed any code in the apps.  Is there something that has changed with iOS8 that has stopped apps from playing audio in the background?

Thanks

Comment: Please, if anyone knows why this would happen please let me know.

Comment: Have you found any documentation on the issue?  It works sometimes and doesn't work other times.  I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: I have found the root of my issue. Any time another wav file plays (even within my own app) it stops my wav file. This was not the case in iOS7. I haven't found a solution yet.